# Polynomial linear regression with Tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorflow-probability

As an exercise, I'm trying to perform a simple polynomial linear regression in tensorflow probability. I'm getting consistent, but bad results.

It's a very simple problem, but somehow I can't see what's going wrong.

```py
import numpy as np

import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd
from tensorflow_probability import sts

series = np.asarray([
    0.1, 0.9, 4.1, 8.9, 16.1
],dtype=np.float32)
n = len(series)

x1 = np.arange(n,dtype=np.float32)
x0 = x1**0
x2 = x1**2

features = [
    (x0,0,10,"x⁰"),
    (x1,0,10,"x¹"),
    (x2,0,10,"x²")
]

model = sts.Sum(
    [   sts.LinearRegression(
            design_matrix = feature.reshape(-1,1),
            weights_prior = tfd.Normal(loc=loc,scale=scale),
            name = name
        )
        for feature,loc,scale,name in features
    ],
    observed_time_series = series
)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
variational_posteriors = (
    tfp.sts.build_factored_surrogate_posterior(model=model)
)

@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def train():
    return tfp.vi.fit_surrogate_posterior(
        target_log_prob_fn = model.joint_log_prob(
            observed_time_series = series
        ),
        surrogate_posterior = variational_posteriors,
        optimizer = optimizer,
        num_steps = 400,
    )

elbo_loss_curve = train()

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
fit_params_samples = variational_posteriors.sample(100000)

for name, p in fit_params_samples.items():
    print(name)
    print(np.mean( p.numpy() ))

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

posterior_samples = variational_posteriors.sample(10000)

component_dists = sts.decompose_by_component(
    model = model,
    observed_time_series = series,
    parameter_samples = posterior_samples
)

samples = [
    np.array(dist.sample(10000))
    for dist in component_dists.values()
]

fit = np.array(samples).sum(axis=0).mean(axis=0)
print(fit)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

with PdfPages('fit-comparison.pdf') as out:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
    plt.margins(x=0)

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

    plt.plot(x1,series,'b',label='data')
    plt.plot(x1,fit,'r',label='fit')

    ax.legend(loc='upper left')

    out.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

Here's an example result.

Parameters:

```
observation_noise_scale
1.4323857
x⁰/_weights
-5.853088
x¹/_weights
-0.14944817
x²/_weights
0.8490697
```

Fitted function:

```
[-5.8690515 -5.1644263 -2.765975   1.3263047  7.1124296]
```

It's consistently giving me `x⁰` between -5 and -6, when it should be close to zero.

Here's what this looks like when drawn.
[image]

I'm using `Python 3.7.13`, `tensorflow 2.4.0`, and `tensorflow-probability 0.12.0`. I'm constrained to these versions, and using `sts.Sum` and `sts.LinearRegression` is part of the point of the exercise.